# python 2 and 3 extract domain from url

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, compatibility, python-2.x

I have an url like: `http://xxx.abcdef.com/fdfdf/`

And I want to get `xxx.abcdef.com`

Which module can i use for accomplish this?

I want to use the same module and method at python2 and python3

I don't like the try except way for python2/3 compatibility

Thanks you so much!

Comment: `url.split('/')[2]` Have you read a full Python tuto? I like this one: http://www.diveintopython.net/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html):

```
from urlparse import urlparse
o = urlparse("http://xxx.abcdef.com/fdfdf/")
print o

print o.netloc
```

In Python 3, you import [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlparse#urllib.parse.urlparse) like so:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
```

Alternatively, just use [str.split()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
url = "http://xxx.abcdef.com/fdfdf/"

print url.split('/')[2]
```

Sidenote: Here's how you write an import of urlparse that will work in either version:

```
if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
if sys.version_info < (3, 0) and sys.version_info >= (2, 5):
    from urlparse import urlparse
```

Comment: `urlparse` is by far the better solution.

Answer (score 8):

You can use 3rd party library six, which takes care of compatibility issues between python versions and standard library function `urlparse` to extract the hostname

so all you need to do is [install six](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990581/how-to-install-the-six-module-in-python2-7) and import urlparse

```
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urlparse
u = urlparse("http://xxx.abcdef.com/fdfdf/")
print(u.hostname)
```

More on urlparse [here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html)