# How to install the Six module in Python2.7

Tags: python, shared-libraries, python-dateutil, six

I am using Python 2.7 and trying to use `dateutil` as follows:

```
from dateutil import parser as _date_parser
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    from dateutil import parser as _date_parser
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\dateutil\parser.py", line 24, in <module>
    from six import text_type, binary_type, integer_types
ImportError: No module named six
```

Could you please let me know what is the `six` module for and how to get it installed in a Windows 7 machine?

Comment: Did you install `dateutil` via pip?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install this

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six

If you still don't know what pip is , then please also google for `pip install`

Python has it's own package manager which is supposed to help you finding packages and 
their dependencies:
http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/

Comment: Isn't it `pip install`

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful and it worked. Also, the pip wiki page was helpful

Answer (score 12):

here's what [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) is:

```
pip search six
six                       - Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
```

to install:

```
pip install six
```

though if you did install `python-dateutil` from pip six should have been set as a dependency.

N.B.: to install pip run `easy_install pip` from command line.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question for macOS.

But the root cause was not installing Six.  My macOS shipped Python version 2.7 was being usurped by a Python2 version I inherited by installing a package via `brew`.

I fixed my issue with:  `$ brew uninstall python@2`

Some context on here:  `https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1061`