# Does the six library comes shipped with default python today?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, six

[How to install the Six module in Python2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990581/how-to-install-the-six-module-in-python2-7) shows that six has to be `pip` installed.

**But does the six library comes shipped with default python python2.7.x and python3.x today?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You can see the list of standard library modules [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/).